# How do I interact with ERC721 smart contracts using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ethereum, nft, flutter-web3

I am looking to create a dapp with Flutter that lets users mint NFT's. I know that there is the Web3 package and I have seen also examples how to interact with ERC contracts. But is it possible to interact with ERC721 contracts with Flutter and Web3? Can someone point me in the right direction? I want to avoid building it in react as I have more experience with Flutter.

Comment: Have you found solution for minting nfts with this package or with flutter?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like author of the [flutter_web3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3) package has it planned as noted in this [recent issue](https://github.com/y-pakorn/flutter_web3/issues/10). Looking at how the ABI is implemented for ERC1155 in [commit #9](https://github.com/y-pakorn/flutter_web3/pull/9/commits/17f8136796dab43fc6db63874e4b8b9a82ec1b54), it doesn't look too difficult to implement ERC721 the same way. If the author can't do this in the next month or so I'll probably take a stab at it myself.

The author also wrote an interesting [article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/building-modern-web-dapp-with-flutter-91656c71d8b) about the basics of writing a flutter application that uses the flutter_web3 package mentioned above.

Comment: Has this been implemented by flutter_web3 or by yourself in the end? Can you update your answer showing how you solved the issue in Flutter? Thanks!

Comment: @RedDeath I didn't implement this because my projects took me down a different path. I may look at it in the future. Maybe check with the author via the GitHub issue where he states he is considering adding ERC721.